# Django 2. Ошибка при загрузки изображения через стили

Tags: css, django

В стилях я пытаюсь вывести изображение путем:

**style.css:**

```
background-image: url("{% static 'images/icons/star.png' %}");
```

**В терминале пишет 404:**

```
"GET /static/css/%7B%%20static%20'images/icons/star.png'%20%%7D HTTP/1.1" 404 1883
```

если прописывать прямую ссылку, то все работает отлично:

```
background-image: url("../images/icons/pointed-star.png");
```

**пробовал делать так:**

```
background-image: url("{% static '../../../images/icons/star.png' %}");
```

тогда в терминале тоже появляется ошибка, но путь, вроде как, указан верно:

```
"GET /static/images/icons/star.png'%20%%7D HTTP/1.1" 404 1830
```

**settings.py:**

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
```

Расположение изображения:

```
static|
       images|
              icons|
                    star.png
```

**В чем может быть проблема? И как ее можно решить? Заранее спасибо.**

Comment: в css не работают теги

Comment: @m0nte-cr1st0 понял, спасибо, я сделал в шаблоне через элемент <style> . Все работает

Answer (score 0):

ну а вообще так

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{%static 'css/style.css' %}" type="text/css">
```

и в css просто

```
background-image: url("pointed-star.png");
```